# "Your browser doesn't support full screen" - WKWebview, macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am currently developing a cocoa web browser application like google chrome. I was testing it until I came across the problem that the wkwebview doesn't support full screen on videos. When I open a video, I get this message...

[image]

I thought I had to make the wkwebview a subview of the view, using this code

```
view.addSubview(webView)
```

I tried it and it still show the image above.

Can you please assist me on supporting full screen.

Comment: You have asked this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61977288/cocoa-youtube-video-does-not-support-full-screen-in-wkwebview

Comment: That's not me, that's a question that is similar to mine

Answer (score 3):

Open your project.
Right click on prject app grade folder from sidebar and click new file.
in choose a template click objective-C file.
name it for example WKPreferences and enter.
Now next window press create.
On next create Bridging-Header.
Now you can see two new files in your sidebar.
Paste following code in WKPreferences.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

Paste following code in Bridge-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WKPreferences ()
-(void)_setFullScreenEnabled:(BOOL)fullScreenEnabled;
@end
```

Now Paste following code in viewcontroller.swift

```
webView.configuration.preferences._setFullScreenEnabled(true)
```

Thats it.

Comment: This actually works. What I'd like to know is how this was discovered because I've been reading Apple's documentation and I never found this.

Comment: @spartygw You can't find any documentation because it's an undocumented private API. This hack could crash in any future update to WebKit. It's not safe for production code. It might work now but it could fail in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```swift
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
if #available(macOS 12.3, *) {
    config.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true
}

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put the following in the Swift-File where the WebView is created:

```
webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "fullScreenEnabled")
```

Comment: Careful with code like this. It could crash in any future update to iOS/macOS.